# Creating a method to calculate the score of a Deck of Cards

Tags: java, arrays, methods, type-conversion, card

So in this Swedish card game (I think it's called 31 or Scat), we have to calculate a deck of 3 cards. If u have 2 spades and 1 diamond your score is either the score of the 2 spades values' added together or the value of that one diamond dependent on which alternative gives you the most points. My system is that I create a method that will evaluate the string array of 3 cards like this: if u have a spade card with a 3 then as a string it's stored "S03" in the array.
In order to see which cards points can be added together I will see if the first character of their string is the same and if so.. Then the 2 other characters will be converted into a number like 03 (3)
Which is what I tried here:

```
int Card1Value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(CardDeck[1].charAt(2))+String.valueOf(CardDeck[1].charAt(3)));
```

The if conditions are my attempt of determining the score.

The reason why my method is a return int is so I can get the playerdeckvalue scores determined

My code:

```
public class CardDecks {
    
public  static int DeckValue( String[] CardDeck) {
        
        
        int Card1Value = Integer.parseInt( String.valueOf(CardDeck[1].charAt(2))+String.valueOf(CardDeck[1].charAt(3)));
        int Card2Value = Integer.parseInt( String.valueOf(CardDeck[2].charAt(2))+String.valueOf(CardDeck[2].charAt(3)));
        int Card3Value = Integer.parseInt( String.valueOf(CardDeck[3].charAt(2))+String.valueOf(CardDeck[3].charAt(3)));
        int AltValue1;
        int AltValue2;
        int AltValue3;
        int CardDeckValue = 0;
        
        if (CardDeck[0].charAt(1)==CardDeck[1].charAt(1) &&
            CardDeck[0].charAt(1)==CardDeck[2].charAt(1)) {
                
            CardDeckValue = Card1Value + Card2Value + Card3Value;
            return CardDeckValue;

        }
            else if (CardDeck[0].charAt(1)==CardDeck[1].charAt(1)) {
              
                AltValue1 = Card3Value;
                AltValue2 = Card1Value+Card2Value;
                CardDeckValue = Math.max(AltValue1, AltValue2);
                return CardDeckValue;

            }
            else if (CardDeck[0].charAt(1)==CardDeck[2].charAt(1)) {
                
                AltValue1 = Card2Value;
                AltValue2 = Card1Value+Card3Value;
                CardDeckValue = Math.max(AltValue1, AltValue2);
                return CardDeckValue;

            }
            else if (CardDeck[1].charAt(2)==CardDeck[2].charAt(1)) {
                
                AltValue1 = Card1Value;
                AltValue2 = Card2Value+Card3Value;
                CardDeckValue = Math.max(AltValue1, AltValue2);
                return CardDeckValue;

            }
            else if (CardDeck[0].charAt(1)!=CardDeck[1].charAt(1) &&
                    CardDeck[0].charAt(1)!=CardDeck[2].charAt(1)) {
                
                AltValue1 = Card1Value;
                AltValue2 = Card2Value;
                AltValue3 = Card3Value;
                
                CardDeckValue= Math.max(AltValue2, Math.max(AltValue2, AltValue3));
                return CardDeckValue;

        }
        return CardDeckValue;
        
        
    
}   
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

          String[] PlayerDeck = new String[]{"K01", "K03", "D10" };
          
          System.out.println( DeckValue(PlayerDeck) );
    
        
    }
}
```

The feedback I got was:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
> String index out of range: 3  at
> java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)     at
> java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:1515)   at
> problem3.DeckValue(problem3.java:8)   at
> problem3.main(problem3.java:69)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Without trying to understand your code...you say that you create representations of the form `"S03"`, which is 3 characters in length.  The error you show is suggesting that you are asking for the 4th character of a string, since string indexes start at `0`.  It sounds to me like you should have a `2` where you have a `3` because you want to ask for the 3rd character in the string, not the 4th.

Answer (score 0):

CharAt(i) actually returns the character at position i in strings. It works because strings are arrays of characters.

In programming, all arrays start at position 0.

When you type CharAt(3), it's looking for the forth character of your string.

0 -> S

1 -> 0

2 -> 3

3 -> out of bounds

Comment: Actually, there are many programming languages in which arrays are 1-based. See the column "First" in the table in the section titled "Array dimensions":  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(array). Java indexes (indices for some) are 0-based for any type of sequence (e.g., arrays, classes based on java.util.List).